# Implement rollback in Nested stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using TRY CATCH block to capture error and do rollback

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_first
/*
parameters
*/
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

/*
statements
*/

  COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF(@@TRANCOUNT>0)
  ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

Will the above approach work if there is another stored procedure  `sp_inner` being called inside `sp_first` which also performs DML statements INSERT , DELETE , UPDATE etc.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_first
/*
parameters
*/
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

/*
statements of sp_first
*/

-- stored procedure sp_inner also requires rollback if error occurs.
EXEC sp_inner @paramaterList

  COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
IF(@@TRANCOUNT>0)
  ROLLBACK
END CATCH
```

How to implement roll back if nested stored procedure is used?

Comment: See [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) - nested transaction are a **myth** in SQL Server - they're not really supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rollback` rolls back to the outermost transaction, not just the current transaction within a transaction. If that is what you are trying to do, then it will work. If not, then it won't.

See General Remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx

Comment: ok , so if all statements are executed successfully inside outer stored procedure `sp_first` but error ocuurs inside `sp_inner` then complete rollback will happen , i.e. rollback inside `sp_innner` and also `sp_first` statements executed succesfully will be rolled back ? I want complete rollback.

Comment: Also do i need to apply begin try rollback mechanism inside inner procedure `sp_inner` or will the outer stored procedure will take care of it .

Comment: The outer will take care.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178157(v=sql.100).aspx) for an example. Basically, as podiluska said, a standard rollback will rollback the entire transaction (meaning, you could have a trancount of 5 and it'll revert all those changes).

You could check the trancount and only roll back that amount, but as per the link, I'd recommend creating a save point prior to calling the nested procedure, and then rolling back to that savepoint in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below snippet will make the concept clear. Whenever the rollback is called in a nested transaction it rolls back all the transactions in the hierarchy starting from the outermost transaction. So when the rollback is called for inner transaction it automatically rolls back the outer  transactions and when we reach the Rollback statement in the outer transaction @@trancount is 0 already and that Rollback is not executed after the check.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
select @@trancount as 'transactioncount1'

 BEGIN TRANSACTION  
    select @@trancount as 'transactioncount2'

 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  
select @@trancount as 'transactioncount3'
IF(@@trancount>0)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```